# Rotate marker as per user direction on Google Maps V2 Android?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Can any one provide an answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704834/rotate-marker-as-per-user-direction-on-google-maps-v2-android).He is explained the query well that's why ain't making new one.it was asked one year ago still no answer.i have to do the same.can any one help me out.?

Comment: You can comment on that question to "bump" it up. It will appear in relevant users feed as Active. Currently its status is inactive. You could also put a bounty on that question since your rep is 75+. It will then be listed in the featured tab to receive more attention. No need to post a new question imo.

Comment: heads up i'm composing an answer for that question now

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33687774/2126510